# IBM MobileFirst 6.3 - Android Fingerprint Authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

I want to implement finger print authentication in my IBM Mobilefirst 6.3 Hybrid Android application. I saw some examples in cordova -

https://github.com/mjwheatley/cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth

Here How can I add cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth plugin to my application? Is there any better way to implement this feature?

I was able to implement touch id in hybrid iOS application.
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-touch-id?cm_mc_uid=04136042670715040496130&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1504217038

Need help to implement similar in Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mobilefirst 7.0 and prior releases does not support Cordova plug-man to install Cordova plug-ins and Hence you can't add plugins directly to your applications using cordova command line.

You need to follow the manual installation instructions as explained in this [blog post](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/) to add `cordova-plugin-android-fingerprint-auth` plugin in your application.